# Where can I find and retrieve server application data from with powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis-7

So I have been tasked with creating a powershell script that will locate and then store data about applications that we are running on servers. This data includes ApplicationName, ComputerName, State, Port, and Path. Let me know if you need more info and thanks in advance!

- Edit: Information to be gathered
- Edit 2: I have determined that I can get the information from iis and I am working on getting it saved to objects and then from the object properties to a database for the information.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Have you thought to google a little bit? `$env:APPDATA`

Comment: So far I have wrote the command to go through each server and I have been searching servers for a common file that contains information but I have yet to identify any kind of common file between applications. I have googled about server applications for the last 2 days and haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up gathering the following information about our IIS Webservices:

- ServerName
- Site State
- Port
- Path to site
- .net version
- Enabled Authentication Types

I was able to achieve this by querying each server and then each website and webconfiguration hosted on that server. Using the commandlets provided in `Import-Module WebAdministration` I was able to run `Get-Website | Foreach-Object` then get the authentication types of each site with `Get-Webconfiguration -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/*"`. I ran this through if statements to return the authentications as enabled = t/f but you can output them to text as well by getting the substring of everything after '/authentication/'. I constructed a list of objects to store all the data [Object Construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxsMM.png) The authentication variables are the outputs of my if statements if you wanted the names alternatively you could just output the array in the console. Finally remember to return the objects from the server invoke command and from your PS function.

Answer (score 0):

I will only give you the tools. You have to start the coding first then.

`Get-ClusterGroup`, `Get-ClusterNode`, `Get-SQLInstance`, `Get-ClusterOwnerNode` will give you the details. You have to put it in variables and map that according to your requirement.

You can create a `PSCustomObject` and map each value accordingly.